# Random variables and $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I came across this problem.

If we throw two dice the sample space is $\Omega = \{ (i, j), 1 \leq i, j \leq 6 \}$. The $\sigma$-algebra is generated by the events $A_k = \{ (i,j) : \max(i,j) = k \}$

Show that $x_1=max(i,j)$ is a random variable and $X_2=i+j$ isn't a random variable

There's a short explanation which explains the relation within the borel sets of the random variable and their preimages.

"Actually, a function $X$ from some measurable space $(\Omega, \Sigma)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is defined as a random variable if it's measurable; that is, for every Borel set B, the preimage $X^{-1}(B) = \{\omega : \omega \in \Omega, X(\omega) ∈ B\}$ is measurable."

"Notice the focus on $X^{-1}(B)$ (preimages of Borel sets) rather than $X^{-1}(x)$(preimages of individual real numbers)"

1) Whenever you have a random variable, are the events of the random variable always borel sets?
I mean if we have that the probability space of the random variable is $(\Omega_X,F_X,P_X)$, then for all the random variables, the family of events $F_X$ is always the $\sigma$-borel algebra?

2) If the preimages $X_1^{-1}(x)$ are $\left \{ 1,2,3,4,5,6 \right \}$, what are the preimages $X_2^{-1}(x)$? And what would be the preimages of $X_1^{-1}(B)$ and $X_2^{-1}(B)$?

How would you show that $X_1$ is a random variable and $X_2$ isn't?

---

Generators of the $\sigma$-algebra, first case:

$A_1=\{(1,1)\}$

$A_2=\{(1,2),(2,2),(2,1)\}$

$A_3=\{(1,3),(2,3),(3,3),(3,2),(3,1)\}$

$A_4=\{(1,4),(2,4),(3,4),(4,4),(4,3),(4,2),(4,1)\}$

$A_5=\{(1,5),(2,5),(3,5),(4,5),(5,5),(5,4),(5,3),(5,2),(5,1)\}$

$A_6=\{(1,6),(2,6),(3,6),(4,6),(5,6),(6,6),(6,5),(6,4),(6,3),(6,2),(6,1)\}$

Here $A_k:=\{(i,j)\in\Omega\mid\max(i,j)=k\}$

---

Generators of the $\sigma$-algebra, second case

$B_2=\{(1,1)\}$

$B_3=\{(1,2),(2,1)\}$

$B_4=\{(1,3),(2,2),(3,1)\}$

$B_5=\{(1,4),(2,3),(4,1),(3,2)\}$

$B_6=\{(1,5),(2,4),(3,3),(5,1),(4,2)\}$

$B_7=\{(1,6),(2,5),(3,4),(4,3),(5,2),(6,1)\}$

$B_8=\{(2,6),(3,5),(4,4),(5,3),(6,2)\}$

$B_9=\{(3,6),(4,5),(6,3),(5,4)\}$

$B_{10}=\{(4,6),(5,5),(6,4)\}$

$B_{11}=\{(5,5),(6,5)\}$

$B_{12}=\{(6,6)\}$

Here $B_k:=\{(i,j)\in\Omega\mid i+j=k\}$

Comment: I took the liberty to edit in order to take away confusion. In the original different sets received the same name. For instance the sets $\{(1,2),(2,2),(2,1)\}$ and $\{(1,1)\}$ were both labeled as $A_2$. This leads to confusion and false statements like $\{(1,2),(2,2),(2,1)\}=A_2=\{(1,1)\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

If by $\Omega_X$ you mean $\mathbb R$ and by $P_X$ you mean the probability measure prescribed by $B\mapsto P(X\in B)$ then: "yes, we usually go for $\mathcal F_X=\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$".

$X$ is usually *by definition* a random variable if it is a function that takes real values and is measurable wrt the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

2)

Looking at $X_1$ the preimage of $B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ wrt $X_1$ is the set:$$X_1^{-1}(B)=\{(i,j)\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}^2\mid max(i,j)\in B\}$$

If you take singleton $B=\{x\}$ then we get:$$X_1^{-1}(B)=\{(i,j)\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}^2\mid max(i,j)=x\}$$

For $X_2$ you will get similar expressions where $\max(i,j)$ is replaced by $i+j$.

---

You cannot speak of "the preimages of $X_1^{-1}(B)$".

The correct wording is that "$X_1^{-1}(B)$ is the preimage of $B$ under (or with respect to) $X_1$".

---

The $\sigma$-algebra generated by the events $A_k$ is formally the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ that contains these sets

Now observe that every preimage $X_1^{-1}(B)$ can be written as a union of these sets. This tells us that $X_1$ is measurable wrt to this $\sigma$-algebra. That means that $X_1$ can be classified as a random variable if $\Omega$ is equippes with the $\sigma$-algebra. Actually the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the $A_k$ can be shown to be  the collection $$X_1^{-1}(\mathcal B(\mathbb R)):=\{X_1^{-1}(B)\mid B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\}=$$$$\{\{(i,j)\in\Omega\mid \max(i,j)\in B\}\mid B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\}\tag1$$

However it is not possible to write e.g. $X_2^{-1}(\{4\})=\{(i,j)\mid i+j=4\}$ as an element of this $\sigma$-algebra.

That's why $X_2$ cannot be classified as a random variable.

---

**edit**:

Working $(1)$ out we find that for every $B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ we can find a set $I=I_B\subseteq\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ such that: $$X_1^{-1}(B)=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$$

So actually: $$X_1^{-1}(\mathcal B(\mathbb R))=\left\{\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\mid I\subseteq\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\right\}$$

For e.g. preimage $X_2^{-1}(\{4\})=\{(1,3),(2,2),(3,1)\}$ we cannot find such a set $I$.

Comment: What does $\left \{ 1,2,3,4,5,6 \right \}^2$stand for? Is the cartesian product?

Comment: Yes, it is the same set as $\Omega$ in your question.

Comment: Singletons must be borel sets then. Why are singletons open sets?

Comment: Yes, singletons are Borel sets. They are not open but that is not necessary for being a Borel set. In fact it is quite hard to find sets that are *not* Borel sets. Note that I added something to my answer which concerns the last sentence in your question.

Comment: Are they closed then?

Comment: Yes, they are closed.

Comment: Thank you. I have some doubts. Can you please explain with more detail how do you generate a $\sigma$-algebra with the events $A_K$?. If I understand rightly the event $A_2=2$, so you would have that all the events $A_k$ are the singletons $\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{5\},\{6\}$. This $\sigma$-algebra, the smallest one, would have $2^6$ elements.These elements are obtained from the initial $6$ singleton by unions and complements. Is this right?

Comment: I got lost here. Can you write an example of the event $A_k$ and an example of  $B_k\in\{A_k,A_k^{\complement}\}$?

Comment: What I wrote is wrong (sorry). It should be $B_k\in\{A_k,\varnothing\}$.

Comment: For instance, what does the event $A_3$ equal to?

Comment: By definition it is the set $\{(0,3),(1,3),(2,3),(3,3),(3,2),(3,1),(3,0)\}$. The set of all tuples $(i,j)$ with $\max(i,j)=3$. It corresponds with singleton $\{3\}$ in the sense that it equals $X_1^{-1}(\{3\})$.

Comment: I don't understand when you say that it is no possible to write $X_2^{-1}(\{4\})=\{(i,j)\mid i+j=4\}$ as an element of this $\sigma-algebra$. You would have that $(i,j)$=  $(1,3),(3,1) (2,2)$

Comment: Well, can you write the set $\{(1,3),(2,2),(3,1)\}$ as a union $\bigcup_{i=1}^6B_i$ where $B_i\in\{\varnothing, A_i\}$ for $i=1,2,3,4,5,6$?... I don't think so. Btw, I see I made a mistake in my former comment. The pairs $(0,3)$ and $(3,0)$ must be left out.

Comment: I have added something to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I wrote the $A_k$'s that generate the $\sigma$-algebra in the OP.  Are you denoting the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the $A_k$'s with $\bigcup_{i=1}^6B_i$ where $B_i\in\{\varnothing, A_i\}$ for i=1,2,3,4,5,6?

Comment: Yes. Also you can write the sets as $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ where $I\subseteq \{1,2,3,4,5,6\} $.

Comment: I think that I don't understand how the sets are generated from a set of generators. When you say"Now observe that every preimage $X_1^{-1}(B)$ can be written as a union of these sets"
Can you please give an example of a preimage as union of these sets?

Comment: $X_1^{-1}([2.5,83))=A_3\cup A_4\cup A_5\cup A_6$ is an example. Note that $X_1^{-1}(B)=X_1^{-1}(B\cap\{1,2,3,4,5,6\})$ since the range of $X_1$ is $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Comment: If we have a set of generators, in this case the $A_k$'s, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the $A_k$'s is the set with the generators, the $A_k$'s,plus all the posible unions, intersections and complements. Here, in the Example section, it's explained what I'm trying to say.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generated_%CF%83-algebra_(by_sets) In our case instead of a $\sigma$-algebra generated by $A$, we have a $\sigma$-algebra generated by the $A_k$'s, but the set should also include all possible unions, intersections and complements. Maybe you can tell me what I'm not understanding.

Comment: We have a $\sigma$-algebra generated by the sets $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_6$ or in other words  by collection $\{A_1,A_2,..,A_6\}$. Elements of this $\sigma$-algebra are all sets of the form $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ where $I\subseteq\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. Observe that this collection is closed under complements and countable unions, so *is* a $\sigma$-algebra. Further it contains the sets $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_6$ (for instance take $I=\{3\}$ to get $A_3$) and is definitely the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ that contains these sets. So it *is* the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{A_1,A_2,\dots,A_6\}$.

Comment: Is it wrong if I say that in the first case, the union of $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ where $I\subseteq\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ is equal to the set $\left \{ 1,2,3,4,5,6 \right \}?$

Comment: Yes you are wrong. Because $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ is not a subset of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. It is a subset of $\Omega$ (as you stated yourself quite well in your question). It will be equal to $\Omega$ in special case $I=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Comment: In the first case, $A_1$={(1,1)} This set has one element,{1};$A_2$={(1,2),(2,2),(2,1)} has two elements {1,2}.If I add $A_1$ and $A_2$ I get the set {1,2}. I can express the same thing as  $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ where $I\subseteq\{1,2\}$. Wrong?

Comment: Yes, wrong. $A_1=\{(1,1)\}$ has indeed one element but that element is not $\{1\}$ but is $(1,1)$. $A_2$ has not two but has $3$ elements: $(1,2),(2,2)$ and $(2,1)$. If by "add" you mean "take  union" (sets cannot be added) then $A_1\cup A_2=\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(2,1)\}$. This can also be expressed as $\bigcup_{i\in\{1,2\}}A_i=\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(2,1)\}$.

Comment: $X_1^{-1}([2.5,83))$$=A_3\cup A_4\cup A_5\cup A_6$.  1)Is the interval$(2.5,83)$ a borel set $B$ such that  $B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$? 2)Is the random variable,(a singleton, x) also a borel set
$B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: Yes it is a Borel set. I don't understand your last question. Singletons $\{x\}\subseteq\mathbb R$ are indeed Borel sets (as I said earlier. But a random variable is not a Borel set. It is a function.

Comment: I meant the outcomes of the random variable $X_1$. In this case $ \{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{5\},\{6\}$.

Comment: Yes, they are singletons and in one of my former comments I already told you that singleton subsets of $\mathbb R$ are Borel sets.

Comment: Thanks. Is the intersection of $\{(1,1)\}$ and $\{(1,2)\}$ equal to $\{1\}$ or the empty set?.

Comment: The empty set. $1$ is not an element of $\{(1,1)\}$ because $\{(1,1)\}$ only has $(1,1)$ as element. Same story for $\{(1,2)\}$ that only has $(1,2)$ as element. Further $(1,1)\neq(1,2)$ so the sets $\{(1,1)\}$ and $\{(1,2)\}$ have no elements in common. Consequently $\{(1,1)\}\cap\{(1,2)\}=\varnothing$.

Comment: Could you please explain with more detail why if every preimage $X_1^{-1}(B)$ can be written as union of the sets $A_k$ then $X_1$ is measurable with respect to this $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Union of the sets $A_k$ is element of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by these sets. So if preimage of each Borel set wrt $X$ is such a union then the preimage of each Borel set wrt $X$ is an element of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by these sets. Then **by definition** $X$ is measurable wrt the $\sigma$-algebra. I think that asking for further details comes close to asking for more confusion. This because actually there are no further details.

Comment: Sorry for asking too much. It is just that I'd like to understand your answer when you say "Now observe that every preimage $X_1^{-1}(B)$ can be written as union of these sets".($A_k$)
For instance, $X_1^{-1}(4)$. How is it written as union of these sets? There is only one set,$A_4$.But on the other hand, I can write $X_2^{-1}([2.5,83))=A_3\cup A_4\cup A_5\cup A_6\cup A_7\cup A_8\cup A_9\cup A_{10}\cup A_{11}\cup A_{12}$.

Comment: **Every** union of these sets can be written as $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ where  $I$ denotes a subset of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\} $. Also if $I=\{4\}$ we call this a union. Then the result is $A_4$. In spite of the fact that there is only one set we still speak of a union. That is common in mathematics. Even if $I=\varnothing  $ we call this a union. Then the result is the empty set. There are $2^6$ such distinct unions and together they form a $\sigma$-algebra.  Sets like $A_8$ are not forbidden but they are irrelevant here because they are empty.

Comment: I see, but what about the second random variable. I can write $X_2^{-1}([2.5,83))=A_3\cup A_4\cup A_5\cup A_6\cup A_7\cup$ $A_8\cup A_9\cup A_{10}\cup A_{11}\cup A_{12}$.(I wrote the "A_k"'s for the second r.v. in the OP) When you say "For e.g. preimage $X_2^{-1}(\{4\})=\{(1,3),(2,2),(3,1)\}$ we cannot find such a set $I$.", in this case the union would be $A_4$ and $I=4$.

Comment: See my comment on your question. In *all* my comments $A_k$ is the set $\{(i,j)\in\Omega\mid\min(i,j)=k\}$. Consequently $X_2^{-1}(\{4\})$ cannot be written as a union of the $A_k$. Yes you can write $X_2^{-1}(\{4\})=B_4$ according to the new notation. But $B_k$ cannot be written as a union of the $A_k$. This reveals that $X_2$ is not measurable wrt to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the $A_k$ and that is exactly what you are asked to prove: "How would you show that $X_1$ is a random variable and $X_2$ isn't?" Under $X_1$ the preimages are unions of the $A_k$ and under $X_2$ they are not.

Comment: If you have the $A_k$'s. You say that you can't get the $B_k$ from the union of the $A_k$. 1) Is it possible to get the $B_k$ from the $A_k$ not only with the union but also with the complements and intersections? 2) In case it is not possible, how do you know?

Comment: No. Suppose that it is possible. Then from that it follows that $B_k$ is an element of the  $\sigma$-algebra generated by the $A_k$. However this $\sigma$-algebra **is** the collection of unions of the $A_k$. A set is element of it if and only if it can be written as a union of the  $A_k$.

Comment: Is it wrong if I say that $X_2$ is a random variable with respect the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $B_k$?

Comment: That is not wrong but is correct.

Comment: Then there's something that I am missing. If we have a r.v. $X_1$ with respect the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $A_k$, and a r.v with respect the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $B_k$, then both are random variables. But you say that the $\sigma$-algebra of $X_2$ should be generated by $A_k$ in order to be a r.v. I don't understand why

Comment: I am only observing that $X_2$ is **not** a random variable wrt the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the $A_k$. That does not exclude that there are $\sigma$-algebras on $\Omega$ such that $X_2$ is a random variable wrt that $\sigma$-algebra. They exist and one of them is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the $B_k$. You are saying  "both are random variables". That however does not have to be true and depends on the question: with which  $\sigma $-algebra is $\Omega$ equipped?